# How to search for each elements of an array in a text file?

Tags: awk

I have an array called `headers`. 
`echo ${headers[@]}` returns `A B C D`. 
I want to search for each of these elements from the first line of a text file and returns the column number where it is situated.

A sample input file could be like this

```
T   A  Z   R   B  E   C  D
10  1  5   0   5  88  0  8
20  8  2   10  2  10  1  45
30  2  33  11  8  25  2  40 
40  7  0   1   1  87  3  96
```

I made a loop over the elements of that array and tried to feed it into a gawk. But somehow it is not searching for those elements in the array.

This is my snippet

```
for ii in ${headers[@]}
do
   echo $ii

  gawk -vtoken="$ii" -F  $'\t' '                                 
     /$token/{                     # This is the line where I tried to feed the element of the header array.                                
        for(f=1;f<=NF;f++){                        
           hdr=$f                                  
          colhdr[f]=hdr                            
          if(index(hdr,"$token"))wanted[f]=1
        }
     } ' inputfile.txt


done
```

Comment: Instead of `/"$token"/` you want `$0 ~ token`

Comment: `for ii in ${headers[@]}
do
   echo $ii

  gawk -vtoken="$ii" -F  $'\t' '                                 
    $0 ~ token {                                                     
        for(f=1;f<=NF;f++){                        
           hdr=$f                                  
          colhdr[f]=hdr                            
          if(index(hdr,"$token"))wanted[f]=1
        }
     } ' inputfile.txt


done` 

This is not working either

Comment: If it's true that `echo $headers returns A B C D` then `headers` is not an array containing 4 strings, "A", "B", "C", and "D", it's a scalar or array containing 1 string, "A B C D".

Comment: Or, it is an array but the first element is "A B C D"

Comment: I checked this and it's an array. 
I just want to adjust my code.

Comment: Try `declare -p headers` to see what it actually is.

Comment: Whatever `headers` is, the awk script I posted is the right way to do this, the way your script is trying to do it is fragile, inefficient and simply doesn't make sense no matter what you're going to use the information it collects/outputs for.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I used this and it's an arry.
  `if [[ "$(declare -p headers)" =~ "declare -a" ]]; then
    echo array
else
    echo no array
fi`

Comment: @EdMorton I get your point. And appreciate your efforts.

Comment: @Frog then `echo $headers` would only output `A B C D` if `headers[0]` contained `A B C D`.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==1 {
    split(headers,tmp)
    for (i in tmp) {
        hdrs[tmp[i]]
    }
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ($i in hdrs) {
            print $i "=" i
        }
    }
    exit
}

$ headers=(A B C D)

$ awk -v headers="${headers[*]}" -f tst.awk file
A=2
B=5
C=7
D=8
```

Comment: Ha, my thoughts almost verbatim!

Comment: Not sure how I should feel about that ;-).

Comment: Hmm, happy that you thought of it faster than me? Or are you wondering about the "great minds think alike, fools seldom differ" spectrum?

Comment: Sure, lets go with that first thing ... :-).